# Como salvar diretório de imagem de formulário no banco

Tags: php, html, mysql, arquivo, phpmyadmin

No sistema que estou desenvolvendo tem um formulário com um campo onde o usuário pode anexar uma imagem.

Após salvo o formulário, o usuário quer visualizar o registro incluindo a imagem, então pensei em salvar a imagem em uma pasta no sistema e o diretório dela no banco de dados.

**Essa é a página do meu formulário:**

```
<form  method="post" action="update-acidentes.php">
                    <fieldset>
                    <h3 class="subhead" style="color:#39b54a;">Clarificação do problema</h3>
                    <div class="form-field">
                        <h4> O que: </h4>
                        <select style="color:#9e9e9e;" name="OQUE" type="text" id="OQUE" aria-required="true" class="full-width">
                            <option>Clique aqui e selecione...</option>
                            <option>Acidente</option>
                            <option>Quase acidente</option>
                            <option>Trajeto</option>
                            <option>Incêndio</option>
                            <option>Acidente impessoal</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <h4> Quem </h4>
                    <div class="form-field">
                        <p style="font-size:20px;"> Nome </p>
                        <input style="color:#9e9e9e;" name="NOME" type="text" id="NOME" placeholder="Insira aqui o nome do colaborador" aria-required="true" class="full-width">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-field">
                        <p style="font-size:20px;"> Descrição do evento </p>
                        <textarea style="color:#9e9e9e;" name="DESCRICAO" type="text" id="DESCRICAO" placeholder="Descreva o ocorrido" aria-required="true" class="full-width"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-field">
                        <p style="font-size:20px;"> Foto </p>
                        <input style="color:#9e9e9e;" name="FOTOA" type="file" id="FOTOA" aria-required="true" class="full-width">
                    </div>
                    <?php require_once('foto-acidente.php'); ?>

                    <div class="form-field">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" style="background-color: #39b54a">Salvar</button>
                    </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
```

**Essa é a página que salva o formulário no banco:**

```
<!--Update de acidentes-->
<?php

    $oque        = $_POST['OQUE'];
    $nome        = $_POST['NOME'];
    $descricao   = $_POST['DESCRICAO'];

    $strcon = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','', 'banco') or die('Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados');
    $sql = "INSERT INTO acidentes (OQUE, NOME, DESCRICAO ) VALUES ('$oque', '$nome', '$descricao')"; 
    mysqli_query($strcon,$sql) or die("Erro ao tentar cadastrar registro" . mysqli_error($strcon));
    mysqli_close($strcon);

    if(isset($_FILES["FOTOA"])){
        $arquivo = $_FILES["FOTOA"];
        //diretorio dos arquivos
        $pasta_dir = "images/arquivosACIDENTES/";
        // Faz o upload da imagem
        $arquivo_nome = $pasta_dir . $arquivo["FOTOA"];
        //salva no banco
        move_uploaded_file($arquivo["FOTOA"], $arquivo_nome);

        $query  = "Insert into acidentes (IMAGEM) values ($arquivo_nome)";
    }

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Salvo com Sucesso !");
            window.history.go(-1);
        </script>';

?>
```

Quando vou salvar um novo registro, aparece a mensagem de salvo com sucesso e quando abro o banco realmente todas as colunas foram salvar exceto a da imagem.

A pasta que eu criei pra armazenas as imagens também está vazia.

Alguém sabe o que pode estar acontecendo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na tag `form` da pagina do formulário você precisa incluir o atributo  `enctype` e definir como `"multipart/form-data"` que indica que o formulário que estamos usando vai trabalhar com o envio de arquivos.

```
<form  method="post" action="update-acidentes.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

**Vários erros na pagina update-acidentes.php**

- Fechando a conexão antes do insert da imagem no banco
- O nome do arquivo imagem é dado por
  `$arquivo = $_FILES['FOTOA']['name'];`
- O diretório da imagem no banco de dados será
  `$arquivo_nome = $pasta_dir . $arquivo;`
- A sintaxe correta para o upload é
  `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["FOTOA"]['tmp_name'], $arquivo_nome);`
- No insert da imagem falta envolver a variável `$arquivo_nome` com aspas simples
  `$query  = "Insert into acidentes (IMAGEM) values ('$arquivo_nome')";`
- Faltou executar a query da imagem
  `mysqli_query($strcon,$query) or die("Erro ao tentar cadastrar imagem" . mysqli_error($strcon));`

Código com as devidas correções

```
<?php

    $oque        = $_POST['OQUE'];
    $nome        = $_POST['NOME'];
    $descricao   = $_POST['DESCRICAO'];
    $arquivo_nome ="";

    $strcon = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','', 'banco') or die('Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados');
    $sql = "INSERT INTO acidentes (OQUE, NOME, DESCRICAO ) VALUES ('$oque', '$nome', '$descricao')"; 
    mysqli_query($strcon,$sql) or die("Erro ao tentar cadastrar registro" . mysqli_error($strcon));

    if(isset($_FILES["FOTOA"])){

        $arquivo = $_FILES['FOTOA']['name'];
        //diretorio dos arquivos
        $pasta_dir = "images/arquivosACIDENTES/";
        // Faz o upload da imagem
        $arquivo_nome = $pasta_dir . $arquivo;
        //salva no banco
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["FOTOA"]['tmp_name'], $arquivo_nome);

        $query  = "Insert into acidentes (IMAGEM) values ('$arquivo_nome')";
        mysqli_query($strcon,$query) or die("Erro ao tentar cadastrar imagem" . mysqli_error($strcon));
    }

    mysqli_close($strcon);

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Salvo com Sucesso !");
            window.history.go(-1);
        </script>';

?>
```

> Vale lembrar que esse script salva no banco da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Talvez fosse mais pratico inserir a imagem na mesma linha

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Neste caso a pagina update-acidentes.php seria

```
<?php

    $oque        = $_POST['OQUE'];
    $nome        = $_POST['NOME'];
    $descricao   = $_POST['DESCRICAO'];

    if(isset($_FILES["FOTOA"])){

        $arquivo = $_FILES['FOTOA']['name'];
        //diretorio dos arquivos
        $pasta_dir = "images/arquivosACIDENTES/";
        // Faz o upload da imagem
        $arquivo_nome = $pasta_dir . $arquivo;
        //salva no banco
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["FOTOA"]['tmp_name'], $arquivo_nome);

    /**************  registro no banco de dados ******************/ 
    $strcon = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','', 'banco') or die('Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados');
    $sql = "INSERT INTO acidentes (OQUE, NOME, DESCRICAO, IMAGEM ) VALUES ('$oque', '$nome', '$descricao', '$arquivo_nome')"; 
    mysqli_query($strcon,$sql) or die("Erro ao tentar cadastrar registro" . mysqli_error($strcon));

    mysqli_close($strcon);
   /**************** fim registro no banco de dados *************/

    }

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Salvo com Sucesso !");
            window.history.go(-1);
        </script>';

?>
```

> Se a imagem não for obrigatória, basta passar as linhas do registro no banco de dados após o fechamento da condicional `if`

Comment: Perfeito. Bem explicativo, resolveu o problema. Obrigada.

Answer (score 2):

bom primeiro de tudo, se você está utilizando um **servidor local**, como o xampp por exemplo, é necessário deixar a pasta com as imagens na mesma pasta do servidor, pois o mesmo não consegue acessar os arquivos de forma externa.

Segundo no seu formulário é necessário adicionar a tag enctype, pois ela permite pegar o valor do caminho da foto através do $_FILES adicione isso no código

```
<form  method="post" action="update-acidentes.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Espero ter ajudado, qualquer coisa estamos ai

Comment: Então, a pasta das imagens está dentro da própria pasta do sistema que está dentro da pasta do EasyPHP. Tentei colocar o enctype como sugeriu mas não aconteceu nada. :(

Comment: Recentemente eu fiz um sistema para inserir o path no banco, meu código está dessa forma $foto = $_FILES["foto"]; if(!empty($foto["name"]))
 $dir = "Foto Perfil/";
 $arquivo_nome = $dir . $foto["name"]; ao Invés de colocar "FOTOA" tente colocar a propriedade name pra ver se funciona

Answer (score 1):

O erro é que você tenta usar o `$arquivo["FOTOA"]` como se ele fosse o nome do arquivo. Ele não é. Esse índice, nem existe. Provavelmente você está recebendo um erro deste tipo:

> **Notice:** Undefined index: FOTOA in ...

O certo é usar assim:

```
    $arquivo_nome = $pasta_dir . $arquivo["name"];
    // envia o arquivo temporário para o diretório
    move_uploaded_file($arquivo["tmp_name"], $arquivo_nome);
```

Além do que foi citado pelo **Alvaro Leandro** que o seu formulário tem que estar assim:

```
<form  method="post" action="update-acidentes.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Esse "tmp_name" é o name do campo no html?

Comment: @MarianaFerreira não... Esse é o local temporário aonde fica o arquivo depois que você o envia.

Comment: No php você consegue pegar algumas informações do arquivo. Se você der um `print_r($_FILES["FOTOA"])` ele irá te retornar algumas coisas como... size - tamanho do arquivo... tmp_name - nome temporário... name - nome do arquivo ... extensão... erros...

Answer (score 0):

Vamos lá,

> 1) Na tag Form adicione a propriedade enctype="multipart/form-data". 
>   2) Verifique o campo que recebe a imagem no banco de dados, se é um char ou varchar de tamanho considerável. 
>   3) no lugar da '/' no diretório do arquivo, utilize a constante php DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
>  ex: 
> **"images".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."arquivosACIDENTES".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR"**

Comment: Então, tentei seguir os passos acima mas também não aconteceu nada de diferente. :(